Simulation of transimpedance amplifier direction of current source
I need to design a circuit which help me to interface a current output sensor to ADC. The sensor is not ready yet. The IC design team is working on it. Only thing I know is the sensor output will be a current.
So I started learning about transimpedance amplifiers and its simulation. I was checking about some simulations. One question came to my mind is the direction of current source. In some reference the current direction is from top to bottom.

Some other places the current direction is from bottom to top.

May I know does this have any significance.
Which direction do I need to select.
Below is the the my initial block diagram.
In all the below images the arrow shows the direction of sensor current flow



Let me ask my question in other way. We can forget about the amplifier part.
I have a sensor which output current. Please see the below image.
In this case what is the direction of current coming from the sensor.
Will it be like shown with green line or red line


Depends if you want the output to go positive or negative. But with no negative supply the latter isn't an option anyway.

If sensor is sourcing the current output will be positive always.Please correct me if I am wrong.

Confused, this is only true for the second circuit with a single positive supply where the output voltage is always positive regardless of the direction of the input current. Would you like me to explain the idea behind this circuit?

I'm referring to the output of U1, which is configured as an inverting amplifier. Positive current coming in from the sensor makes a negative voltage output.

@Finbarr,I am concerned about the direction of current flow from sensor,I think it will be always out from the sensor so we need to model as shown in the second image

@Circuitfantasist,I am concerned about the direction of sensor current flow.I assume always current is coming out from the sensor and I am assuming current coming out is positive.So I need to model as 2nd figure

Current comes out of one side of the sensor and goes into the other, it's up to you how you connect it. Unless there's more to it but presumably you don't know that yet anyway so everything right now is guesswork.

I'll start by pointing out that those two circuits are identical with two exceptions:

The op-amps have different supply potentials, which dictates the maximum and minimum output potential.

The non-inverting inputs are held at different potentials, which determines output potential for zero input current.


My answer here employs the same design, but tries to address those differences.
If the op-amp is rail-to-rail output, with supplies equalling the ADC's input voltage range, then you can connect the amplifier output directly to the ADC, without worrying about post-processing such as clamping.
Then, if that op-amp also has rail-to-rail inputs, then you can bias it to produce any output offset you desire. By having the output stay near the positive rail, you can have rising input current cause the output to fall, or vice versa.
Here I use the AD8551 with supplies of 0V and +3.3V, ensuring that an ADC expecting a signal within that same range won't get any nasty surprises:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
By adjusting R2 so that \$V_{BIAS}=+1.65V\$, half way between the supply rails, the output can swing in either direction, meaning that input current can be positive (a source) or negative (a sink):

The op-amp output will clip if the input swing is too great (within reason), keeping the ADC safe:

If in the end it turns out that the sensor sources current, which would cause output potential to fall, then adjust R2 to bias the output to some high value when \$I_1=0\$, say \$V_{BIAS}=+3.2V\$:

simulate this circuit
As input current \$I_1\$ goes from zero to 50μA, this would be the corresponding output \$V_{OUT}\$:

Flipping the current direction, so that it sinks instead, would require that you set \$V_{BIAS}=0.1V\$ or so, allowing the output to rise from that base level:

simulate this circuit

In practice you probably wouldn't use the +3.3V rail as a source for bias voltage, as I have done above, unless you are sure that power supply is very stable and noise free, since any fluctuation in that 3.3V will appear at the output. It would be better to employ a precision reference, like the good old TL431 to obtain a separate clean +3.3V, from a 5V (or higher) supply:

simulate this circuit
